# Multiple Oracle Instances cause problems

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-assembly, gac, odp.net

I had been using 1 oracle client and everything was fine, but I had to install 2 more different versions of Oracle. And it's causing problems now.

1. Toad started throwing exception popup which says "access violation at address in module oran11.dll".
2. OracleConnection of ASP.NET application started throwing empty exception.

I solved 1 by rearranging path values in system environment variables, putting the original Oracle path before than others. But still struggling with 2, I looked into dll loading by Process Explorer. And it looks like loading wrong oracle dlls like one from 11.2 and another from 12.1.

Of course I can try to fix this by uninstall all these oracles, and reinstall only one. But I have to keep these 3 for different development settings.

How can I fix these oracle path problems? Does anyone have clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the older "unmanaged" provider, ODP.net is made up of a managed part (oracle.dataaccess.dll) and an unmanaged part (nearly all the other dlls in the oracle home directory).  When oracle.dataaccess.dll is loaded up it goes thru the following search order to find the unmananged dlls that it needs:

> The Oracle.DataAccess.dll searches for dependent unmanaged DLLs (such
>   as Oracle Client) based on the following order:
>
> ```
> Directory of the application or executable.
>
> DllPath setting specified by application config or web.config.
>
> DllPath setting specified by machine.config.
>
> DllPath setting specified by the Windows Registry.
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_ MACHINE\Software\Oracle\ODP.NET\version\DllPath
>
> Directories specified by the Windows PATH environment variable.
> ```
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/InstallODP.htm

My first guess is that you have an old version of oracle.dataaccess.dll in your bin directory.  Your simplest fix is to specify a "DllPath" configuration variable and point to the old oracle home for that asp.net site:

```
<configuration>
 <oracle.dataaccess.client>
   <add key="DllPath" value="C:\app\user\product\11.1.0\your_old_client\bin"/>
   ...
```

Another thing you could try is deleting it - that way, it may load a "better" dll from the gac (even if the version you installed was newer, the installer typically installs publisher policies to redirect any references, at least for the same major version).  I say that only to give some insight on how to avoid the situation in the future.  I have another answer on the subject here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15509914/852208

Comment: Thanks!!! This didn't solve my problem but was a good clue to look into more. I found machine.config was set to newer version, so tried to change it, it changed a bit the symptom but couldn't fix my original problem. So decided to uninstall all and reinstall one which I need right now.

Answer (score 0):

Those assemblies are saved in the GAC.

Go to `C:\Windows\assembly`, select those assemblies you want to get rid off, right-click and choose `Uninstall`. Those assemblies will not get loaded any more by your program.

If you have to re-install them, they are still in the Oracle folder, so you can install it from there again using `gacutil`.

Comment: Thanks but those dlls(oraons.dll, oraops12.dll and so on) are being loaded from their installed path by QTAgent32.exe. That's why I thought this is a problem related to path. They are not in the c:\windows\assembly\

Comment: Your problem with TOAD was solved, right? It was only about the second problem, right? Also, TOAD doesn't use .NET.

Comment: Yes, Toad problem was solved. only second one is bothering me :(

Comment: But that question hasn't to do anything with TOAD, right? So removing the assemblies from the GAC solves the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. I rearranged path values in 'system environment variables' to solve first problem, so I'm assuming the second problem might be related to path things also. And there are no dlls which look like causing problems in GAC.