# Specific Version = False ignored for Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: c#, visual-studio, odp.net

My DB Utilities project has a reference to `Oracle.DataAccess 2.112.3.0`, which is set as Specific `Version = False`, however projects that reference this `DB Utilities` are requiring this exact `version (2.112.3.0)` as you might check on the images below.

Why is this happening?

[image: Oracle.DataAccess reference]

[image: GAC]

Comment: This is normal, the setting only applies to a check on the version of the *reference assembly*.  Getting a version mismatch at runtime is far nastier, you don't have the compiler anymore to keep you out of trouble.  The CLR insists on an *exact* version match.  Telling it to ignore a mismatch requires using the `<bindingRedirect>` in the app.config file.  Best avoided.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if a user doesn't have the version I'm redirecting too, the same error will happen.

Comment: If you make the mistake of leaving it up to your customer to supply the data provider, then yes, you have to tell them what version you need.  That's not where it ends, also be explicit about what version of the .NET Framework you need and what operating system version you support.

Comment: If you are concerned with deployment issues, you could embed the 10MB ODP.NET Managed Driver in your app, or use the XCopy ODP.NET Unmanaged driver to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole bunch of things that are standing out with this beyond the version of the oracle provider.

For starters, I second just including the managed provider in your project.

For your specific case, runtime issues are different than compile time issues.  Despite 'require specific version', you are still compiling against a specific version.  If one of your DBUtils methods is returning a reference to an OracleConnection, it's returning a specific version of that OracleConnection and callers of that method are expecting that specific version at compile time.  Once you run, require specific version=false allows you to change out the dll as long as the signatures match.

Another option is that you leave specific version = true, and instead rely on publisher policies that are included with ODP.net.  That way you rely on Oracle to say what versions are safe to use and avoid some of the flakiness that's going to come with running against a completely different version.  See the screen shot in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15509914/852208

But I've got to ask - I'm not exactly sure what your DBUtils does, but I wonder how necessary it is if you still need a reference to the db provider that it is providing tools for.  In all my years, I've never had a DBUtils library.  I've had data access layers that completely abstracted away the db calls, or I simply had my business library that made the db calls directly.  I've never needed something in between.

Last, when I do create client app over a web app, I still create a webservice for the client app to call and one of the biggest reasons is to avoid the need for clients to have the db provider altogether.  Not only do you skip this extra local requirement, but you also skip the mess of trying to secure your database (unless you're prompting the user for database credentials).